# How to deregister scripts all at once

Tags: jquery, javascript, scripts

How can I deregister all wordpress scripts all at once except for the admin? I have looked at the discussion [How can I de-register ALL styles all at once? And same with Javascript?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17131/how-can-i-de-register-all-styles-all-at-once-and-same-with-javascript), but i do not want to get the scripts enqueued just deregister them. The scripts should work for the admin.

Answer (score 0):

Its already answered on this [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17131/how-can-i-de-register-all-styles-all-at-once-and-same-with-javascript)

```
<?php
//To remove all script from the page
function remove_all_scripts() {
    global $wp_scripts;
    $wp_scripts->queue = array();
}
//  to remove all stylesheet
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'remove_all_scripts', 100);

function remove_all_styles() {
    global $wp_styles;
    $wp_styles->queue = array();
}
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'remove_all_styles', 100);
?>
```

It will remove all the scripts enqueued by standard method. Manual script will not be removed.

Hope it will help

Comment: but how to make sure that the deregistered scripts work for the admin user

Comment: Just add this script in you custom plugin then. Firebug to check.