# Easiest way to find JS conflicts

Tags: javascript, buddypress, wp-register-script

What is the best / easiest way to find JS conflicts?

I have a subpage where I load jQuery OwlCarousel which works fine, but sometimes does not set the active item correctly.

So I suppose there is a conflict with some other jQuery UI / drag/drop Plugin or similarly, hence may owlCarousel does sometimes not properly catch the relevant event(s) (in this case the drag/drop event) to set the active css class.

I mean I could potentially unregister ALL scripts (e.g. [How can I de-register ALL styles all at once? And same with Javascript?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17131/how-can-i-de-register-all-styles-all-at-once-and-same-with-javascript) ) and than enable them via whitelist one by one - very annoying and cumbersome as I have a Buddypress / Buddyboss website which has LOADS of Javascript files...

Is there an easier way, maybe to find out via Chrome WebDev? Can I someone disable relevant callback events to find a quicker way to the root cause?

Thanks so much!

Comment: You don't have to unregister scripts via wordpress for this debugging. You can use **block request url** in chrome devtools, go to network, select js tab, refresh, right mouse click on a js file name, choose block request url. Much quicker for debugging, I use this method alot while developing.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast: Thanks, do you know when blocking a script after loading has finished, whether this will avoid the conflicts already or whether the blocking will be saved and I have to reload the page?

Comment: After you blocked a request you will need to refresh the page. After refresh, that file will not be requested, so any logic in that file will not be executed. I can't say that that will solve the problem but that is the debugging process. Block requests until you find the culprit.